Will I punish somebody by selecting a better answer?
If I select an answer as the best one, and tomorrow somebody writes a better answer and I select that instead, does the first guy get his points subtracted?
I often don't select the best answer because of that.

You accept answer based on merit. What answer you feel has answered your question completely should be considered accepted. See: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

I'm assuming you're talking about accepted answers here, which are the answers that helped you the most, not neccessarily the best. And yeah, they do lose the 15 points.
But, also 15 points isn't that much, nor is it that important. Punishment is a strong term. I'd call it "relocating a gift".
